# Is hashing really a irreversible process?

Tags: security, encryption, hash, aes, sha

I've been using hash and RSA for a time(on a very superficial level, for ex: RSA authentication on a SSH connection), and I want to learn more about it.

To begin with, I know that encryption is a two-way process that can be reverted. And hashing is a one-way process that is irreversible.

That last point just doesn't make sense to me, if I use an algorithm to hash "hello", wouldn't the same algorithm, but "reversed"(meaning, it works "backwards"), be able to convert that hash to "hello" again.

EDIT:

Thanks to @GeorgDangl, @klutt, and Pete Kirkham for pointing out that I didn't understand at all the concept of "irreversible math". The examples were really helpful.

Comment: It's because your input space (plain text) is bigger than your output space (hashes). This means that for every distinct output (hash), there are multiple inputs that lead to this hash. For example, a server that verifies a password against a stored hash might accept a different password that just happens to have the same hash output (this is, for example, used in attacks with Rainbow Tables)

Comment: Maybe OP could have spent a little bit more research effort, but I do not see the need to DV. The question is very clear and interesting for others. I upvoted it.

Comment: @DiegoS I'm very aware that's trivial. As a matter of fact i already had checked wikipedia, but as it's not the best place to look for information i checked other resources. Due to my lack of knowdlege i'm unable to discern what's true from what's not (aka. outdated info &/or mistaken info). That's why I asked the question.

Comment: Even if the input space is smaller than the output space a (cryptographic) hash is not reversible. All that is needed to produce this is to loose some information on purpose, say ignoring an integer addition overflow. Nota Bene: Cryptographic hashes are a special class of hashes and in general are designed to be irreversible and collision resistant. Hashes such as for fast lookup as with dictionaries may be very simple and may have substantial collisions that are resolved be other methods.

Comment: @zaph What you're saying is true, but I want to point out that if the input space is larger than the output, then it is always irreversible. Input space being larger is a sufficient, but not necessary condition for irreversibility.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is solely a question about [crypto.se] and not about programming.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is irreversible in the sense that for each input you have exactly one output, but not the other way around. There are multiple inputs that yields the same output.

For any given input, there's a lot (infinite in fact) different inputs that would yield the same hash. This is easy to realize since the output has a fixed size, but the input doesn't have size restrictions.

To achieve this, irreversible math is used. For instance, it is easy to calculate `10%3`. The answer to that is simply `10%3=1`. But if I give you the equation `x%3=1`, what would you do? This equation is true for all `x=3*k+1`. Thus, you cannot get the number I started with.

Another example of irreversible math is sine and cosine. For instance, `cos(0)=1`, but there are more input values that evaluates to 1. Actually, `cos(n*2pi)=1`. There are "inverses" to these functions, but they either gives an answer in a certain range or a multivalued answer. A third example is `x²=1`. This is true for both `x=1` and `x=-1`. However, in this example you get a finite (and also rather small) number of possible answers.

When dealing with encryption, one could say that the private key is used to pick the right solution. You can always quite trivially decrypt an encrypted message, but you will get a huge load of possible answers. The key is used to find the right one, rather than actually decrypting.

Another thing worth mentioning is that a good hash algorithm minimizes for collisions, that is, two inputs generating the same hash. Also, when it comes to cryptography, you want it to be as hard as possible to reverse it. But this also comes with the cost that algorithms are cpu intensive.

A very basic and insecure hash algorithm could look like this pseudocode:

```
hash = 0
for each byte in input:
    hash = hash + byte
```

Here I assume that `hash` is a simple integer variable that wraps around when it comes to it's maximum value. The algorithm is easy to implement, and it's quick. But you don't want to use it if security is important. It's typically very easy to modify a file so that this hash check won't detect it.

Real cryptographic hash algorithms strives to achieve the property that if you change **any** single bit in the input, **every** single bit in the output have a 50% chance of flipping. Furthermore, if you flip two bits in the input, the bits flipped in the output will be totally unrelated to which bits would flip if you just changed the bits one by one.

I found a good youtube video on the subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoMOAIzBSpY

Comment: Another worth to mention property of a good hash function is dispersion, you should call it it. Let's say you store your user passwords hashed, if more than one number returns the same hash it means you can authenticate the same user with more than one password.

Comment: @DiegoS Good point. I'll consider it. I'm afraid the answer becomes a little bit to broad then.

Comment: @zaph I think that what Diego meant is that, each input has always the same output, but more than one input can lead to that same output.

Comment: @zaph There's nothing strange about it at all. It does not suggest that there's no collisions. Its just plain fact. It's called that it is a [surjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) function.

Comment: @klutt: I think that you should not call the output "unique", because it is not unique. I'm not a native speaker, so maybe that first sentence is OK, but for me, it is highly misleading, and if I try to understand, what you mean by "not the other way around", I fail. You may want to say this differently.

Comment: @klutt In math, maybe it's true, but in everyday life, I think unique means something else. If I have a unique car, then I have a type of car, which **only I** have. That's why it's unique. If my friend has the same type of car, then my car is not unique anymore.

Comment: @klutt: I disagree with you. Computer science is not math. Maybe in a math document, it is perfectly fine to use unique the way you used it (Perhaps you used this word, because you have a math background?), but in CS, it is not. I've never seen unique used that way. Please, do a search, for example, "cryptography unique". I've checked the first ~10 results, and all the results used unique not in a way you use it. For example, when they talk about "unique key", they mean that only one entity has this key, not "there is one and only one key".

Comment: Most cryptographic hash functions (CHF) are not *known* to be surjective, though they are all conjectured to be. You are using the term "surjective" where the simpler term "function" should be used. "Surjective" means that *every* possible output is achieved for some input. The manner in which CHFs are constructed makes this seemingly impossible to prove, and their output spaces are too large to verify empirically.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I changed it now. Not because it's wrong, but because it would clutter the answer if I elaborated fully why it is surjective. For instance, a function is not surjective on it's own. We need to *choose* input and output spaces. It is fully reasonable to *choose* the output space such that it is the set of all *possible* values that the function can produce. We may not know if a certain hash is possible to produce, but if it isn't, then it does not belong to the output space by definition.

Comment: "The key is used to find the right one, rather than actually decrypting." This magically sums it for me!!

Answer (score 6):

Trivial example - say that for our irreversible function, we take the number we are input and return the value modulo 7.

```
   hash( 0) => 0
   hash( 1) => 1
   hash( 2) => 2
   hash( 3) => 3
   hash( 4) => 4
   hash( 5) => 5
   hash( 6) => 6
   hash( 7) => 0
   hash( 8) => 1
   hash( 9) => 2
   hash(10) => 3
   hash(12) => 4
   hash(13) => 5
   hash(14) => 6
```

so if the hash value is 6, you don't know if the input was 6, or 14, or any value of 6 + 7 * N where N is an integer.